# Why do I get positive amplitudes when I create a qiskit StateVectorCircuit from only negative amplitudes?

Tags: quantum-state, qiskit, simulation

I am using amplitude encoding to encode my features in a quantum circuit. With this I expect to encode e.g. 32 features in five qubits.

For the encoding I use qiskit's `StateVectorCircuit`. I expect to receive the same state vector when using the `StateVectorCircuit` with the 'statevector_simulator' as I put in.

However, I experienced, that the sign of the real part (I don't use complex numbers) doesn't matches.

Here is a small example:

```
state_vector = [-1/2, -1/2, -1/2, -1/2]

state_vector_circuit = StateVectorCircuit(state_vector).construct_circuit()

job = execute(state_vector_circuit, Aer.get_backend('statevector_simulator'), optimization_level=0)
result = job.result()

outputstate = result.get_statevector(state_vector_circuit)

print(outputstate)
print(state_vector)
```

Running this code, I receive the following output, where the second line is the expected one:

```
[0.5+0.j 0.5+0.j 0.5+0.j 0.5+0.j]
[-0.5, -0.5, -0.5, -0.5]
```

Measuring the circuit will have the same results. However, I don't want to measure it immediately instead I have this circuit as an input for my Quantum Neural Network. And, in this case I guess the sign matters.

Where is the wrong sign coming from? Is it the `StateVectorCircuit` or the 'statevector_simulator'? And more importantly is there a way from preventing this?

On the other hand, I figured I could use only positive amplitudes. However, I feel this would be a limitation.

**Edit:** I created an example jupyter notebook on my GitHub page: [StateVectorCircuitTest.ipynb](https://github.com/danielmpla/quantum-stackexchange-shares/blob/master/StateVectorCircuitTest.ipynb)

Answer (score 1):

Your target state and the state that you get only differ by a total factor of $-1$.
In other words, if $|\psi\rangle$ is the state that you get and $|\psi_{t}\rangle$ is the target state, we have:

$$
|\psi\rangle = (-1)\times|\psi_{t}\rangle = -|\psi_{t}\rangle.
$$
Such a overall factor is known as a *global* phase. People think of it as a phase, because we can write $-1 = e^{i\phi}$ for $\phi=\pi$. Note that we're not only considering global phases when $\phi$ *is* equal to $\pi$, but $\phi$ can be anything between $0$ and $2\pi$.

We don't care about global phases, because whenever we try to retrieve information (i.e. a measurement) from a state the global phase **cannot** play a role. Therefore, we normally just disregard the global phase, and we set the first entry in our statevector to a real, positive value.

The sign difference between elements in your statevector, however, *does* play a vital role. We call this the *relative* phase, as it is a phase of one element of the statevector relative to the other. Also note that if you limit yourself to only real elements (thereby setting any relative phase $\phi_{rel}$ to $0$ or $\pi$), you severely limit the quantum advantage that you can attain.

Comment: But is it the ```StateVectorCircuit``` or the 'statevector_simulator', which is setting the first entry to a real, positive value and can I prevent this from happening? Trying my example above with ```[-1/2, 1/2, 1/2, -1/2]``` I get ```[1/2, -1/2, -1/2, 1/2]```, which is exactly what you wrote!

Comment: My guess would be that it happens as soon as you make anything 'quantum' out of it - so in the line where you specify the StateVectorCircuit. I also don't expect you to be able to prevent this from happening - if you check the source code (https://qiskit.org/documentation/_modules/qiskit/aqua/circuits/statevector_circuit.html) you can see that upon initialization of the StateVectorCircuit object the internal state_vector proprty is normalized. This normalization is probably deleting the global phase.

Comment: Furthermore, there is not really a circuit that you can device to actually get such a 'negative' statevector - the operations that we can perform on qubits just don't respect global phases, overall.

Comment: I've found, that the following [circuit](https://algassert.com/quirk#circuit={%22cols%22:[[%22X%22],[%22Z%22],[%22H%22,%22H%22],[%22%E2%80%A2%22,%22X%22],[%22Z%22]]}) creates the desired state, also with the 'statevector_simulator'. So, it seems the ```StateVectorCircuit``` is the 'problem'.

Comment: Nice work! Btw, in the circuit that you've linked, the entangling gate is not necessary (it actually does nothing), so you can omit it. So [this circuit](https://algassert.com/quirk#circuit={%22cols%22:[[%22X%22],[%22Z%22],[%22X%22],[%22H%22,%22H%22]]}) actually also does the trick, but no 'real' quantum computer would actually implement the first three gates.

Answer (score 0):

If your circuit is a component of a larger circuit then global phase may matter. See relevant discussions in https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-aer/issues/353 and https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-terra/issues/3083.

Comment: After looking into the issues and the code of the ```StateVectorCircuit``` I guess the problem lies at https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-aqua/blob/bbb083f9918c1e1492e3b3417fca34dd1215e8b6/qiskit/aqua/circuits/statevector_circuit.py#L90, is there a way for disabling this behavior in your opinion?